# TCL: List concat doesnt work

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

I am trying to join the below two elements as a single list 
Tried concat , join , lappend etc but its not working

```
1134-1215 { W.1.Agg-251 ethernet4/28 island ethernet9/7}
```

I need the output of (links)list whose 1st element is 1134 , second element as W.1.Agg-251  etc

```
 for {set index 0 } { $index <=328 } {incr index} {
     lappend links   [lindex $result2 $index] [lindex $list4 $index]
 }

 puts "===>$links"
```

where result 2 is a list like {1134-1150 1151-1600 .. }
and   list4 is a list like {W.1.Agg-251 ethernet4/28 island ethernet9/7 X.1.Agg-251 ethernet4/29 island ethernet9/9... }

Comment: The problem isn't in this part of the code. Have you checked what `$result2`, `$list4` and `$links` are when you enter the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to do something like

```
set links [concat $links [lindex $result2 $index] [lindex $list4 $index]]
```